# How to create a list of the last 20 reports opened with Report Studio?

Tags: cognos

During the work week, I jump around a lot doing several different things. I don't get to spend dedicated time in Cognos Report Studio. I tend to work on a lot of different stuff all the time. It would be nice if Report Studio offered a way to see the last 20 reports I was working on. This would be similar to how Microsoft Excel keeps track of the most recent spreadsheets that were opened.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to show the last 20 reports that were opened with Report Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create special report for it.
Use Cognos audit package and create report based on COGIPF_ACTION table.
Use COGIPF_OPERATION field to filter out only actions you need.
Use COGIPF_TARGET_PATH field to get object.
You even can create URL to open this report in Report Studio.

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a champ. :-)